# I concatenated two pictures with the "copy /b" commande, and now I want to get the two images back. How can I do this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, merge, concatenation

So, like the title say, how can I do this? I noticed that the file size has increased, so the two files are really concatenated, and I deleted the original ones, now how can I unmerge the two pictures?

Comment: Do you know what image format they are in?  You'll probably need to determine how big the first image is, which can probably be done by finding a known "header" (common start of a file) from the second image.  This can be done (via dd, and I'm sure some other methods too).  Unfortunately, I'm not available at the minute to flesh our a full answer, but figured I'd help get you start a bit.

Comment: How about a bit of PowerShell.  If I run: `copy /b 1.jpg+2.jpg 3.jpg` I will get `3.jpg`.  If I create some PS to look for all occurrences of a magic sequence of bytes in the file I can find the offsets and then write out each file. See https://pastebin.com/atVnmBLE as a quick example.  In this case, I have used the magic sequence for jpg `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01`. You could check the first file with the command: `$(format-hex .\3.jpg)[0]` in a PS window. This script assumes they are all the same type. Hope it offers an idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the [file header structure](https://file-extension.net/seeker/) for the images, e.g. [Windows Bitmap begins 0x**4D42**](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html) and [JPEG begins 0x**FFD8**](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html).
2. Open the concatenated file in a hexadecimal (hex) editor, e.g., [HexEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hexedit/).
3. In the hex editor, search for the invariant header string (not the subsequent information, such as image dimensions).
4. Using the hex editor, save each portion under different names.

*N.B.* Within the file, there may be random additional occurrences of the header bytes *within actual image information* due to random chance; it's up to you to determine where the the second image begins.

BTW, the technical term for what you accomplished is [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), hiding data inside other information. The oldest known examples might be those mentioned by Herodotus about 2,500 years ago.